# Custom Shaped Layout

Tags: android, svg

Before you give me solutions like a `svg background` or a `layer-list` or something similar, what I actually need / or what I want to know if it's possible, is changing the shape of a layout.

So, I am using something to add views inside a layout, but my layout is a square, what I actually need is something more complex than that.

Supposing I have a `svg of a t-shirt` I want to be able to add views only inside that `t-shirt svg` like, everywhere inside..

Question: is it possible or not ? Any other ideas that might work this out somehow ?

public void addChildToPlayableArea(int drawableId, int tag){
        StickerImageView stickerImageView = new StickerImageView(getActivity());

I am not sure that this will help you, but I have this StickerImageView, that I have to add inside a FrameLayout in order to be able to move and resize the image.

```
stickerImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(drawableId));
    stickerImageView.setId(tag);
    if (Objects.equals(TAGS.SHAPE_TAG, tag))
        stickerImageView.setControlsVisibility(false);
    playableArea.addView(stickerImageView);
}
```

What I did for now is to define the sizes of this `FrameLayout` based on the parent(which contains the t-shirt)

```
private void setPlayableAreadDimensions(int scaleW , int scaleH, boolean moveZone){
    Log.i(TAG, " H : " + playableArea.getLayoutParams().height +
            "W : " + playableArea.getLayoutParams().width);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = product.getLayoutParams();

    Log.i(TAG, " H : " + params.height +
            "W : " + params.width);

    playableArea.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(product.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth() / scaleW, product.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() / scaleH));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) playableArea.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    playableArea.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    Log.i(TAG, "Playable area H : " + playableArea.getLayoutParams().height +
                    "\nPlayable area W : " + playableArea.getLayoutParams().width);

}
```

**I am sorry if the question doesn't respect stackoverflow standards**

Comment: Sure, the <use> element would likely be the way to go.

Comment: why don't you use image

Comment: What does "only inside that svg, everywhere inside" mean exactly?  It's not very clear to me. A mockup image would be helpful.

Comment: Custom drawing of a shape is possible. Extend a View and get working in `onDraw()`

Comment: Well, I don't think that `Drawing a custom View` would help me... I need a `FrameLayout` so I can add childs to it (Images / texts)

Comment: @PaulLeBeau imagine a simple `t-shirt svg` like a shape and when I add childView i want it to be added inside this area only.

Comment: @pskink but idea is that I don't want this area to be a square :D

Comment: @ionut-j-bejan So then it sounds like you mean that any graphics on the t-shirt take the shape of the t-shirt, and their edges get clipped to the shape of the t-shirt?  If so, then you could use an SVG `<mask> or `<clipPath>`. Or you could use `Canvas.clipPath()` to set a clipping path for all the views inside your custom ViewGroup/FrameLayout.

Comment: Or even just cheat. Make a white rectangle with a t-shirt-shaped hole cut out of it. Then layer it on top of the view that holds all the t-shirt graphics.

Comment: I tried to "cheat" and I calculated an area inside the tshirt. @PaulLeBeau the childViews doesn't have to take the shape of the t-shirt because I can play with them inside that area (resize / rotate / etc) I just want to make sure they don't go out of t-shirt bounds

Comment: Oh. So you mean you don't want people to place the views outside the boundary of the t-shirt? How are they placing them?  Please update your question and describe what you want to do clearly, so we don't have to keep asking questions.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau this is what I could provide in terms of code. I have a `RelativeLayout` with a `FrameLayout` inside and I will set it's dimensions based on the `RelativeLayout` , but yea, I end up with a `square`... Here is where the change should be made, this `FrameLayout` should take the shape of the shirt . Hope you got me

Comment: @pskink a `StickerImageView` which has as superclass `FrameLayout`

Comment: @pskink my problem is not scaling the views that I add... is the zone where I add them, I want it to be custom and to have exactly same bounds as a t-shirt shape! This custom view `StickerImageView` already do the scaling / move / etc

Comment: If performance is not much of an issue (at least at launch), here's a possible way of approaching it. Extend FrameLayout. In onDraw() method, draw your T-shirt. This is the easy part. Now once the T-shirt is drawn once, you can run an algorithm on it to determine the path from it (ie scan every pixel, get rid of the transparent one and you should be left with the shape of the T-shirt). Once you have this shape, you can clip the canvas by creating a Path matching this T-shirt shape. Everything added onto this child will then be clipped to the T-shirt "real bounds"

Comment: @NSimon exactly this I was trying to do this morning, but I couldn't manage to determine that `clip - Path` ..

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan You could have a look at http://www.tomgibara.com/computer-vision/canny-edge-detector and see what results it gives you, but it'd seem like a solid start to determine the shape of your T-shirt

Comment: I don't think it is possible to determine that from a drawable .. @NSimon